# PyInstaller: launch another Python process with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

How do I launch another Python process with `subprocess` from within a PyInstaller executable?

That is, I have a Python script that I compile with PyInstaller to an executable. Inside this Python script, at some point I need to launch another Python process with `subprocess` (I have a good reason for using `subprocess` instead of `multiprocessing` here, namely because it seems to be the only way to open the new process in a new console window, with `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE_WINDOW` on Windows):

```py
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "some.module", ...])
```

However this approach doesn't work, because when the PyInstaller-compliled executable runs, `sys.executable` is no longer a path to the Python interpreter, but rather it's the path to the executable itself. I don't want to use just "python" either because I want to make sure it's using the exact same Python interpreter that is used to run the main program.

---

Another reason for using `subprocess` is that if I find out a way to start a Python process by explicitly calling the interpreter as above (with the argument list `[sys.executable, ...]`), I will be able to use the async version of subprocesses, `asyncio.subprocess`, which has an API very similar to `subprocess`. There doesn't seem to be an asyncio equivalent of `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Use `multiprocessing` to start a controlled set of new processes without needing to know the path to the Python executable.

Comment: If you still require Python to run the executable, doesn't that defeat the purpose of compiling it to an executable?

Comment: @IgnaceVau I need multiple processes to run some code in parallel. Since my code is in Python, these processes must be Python processes. Admittedly, `multiprocessing` is the best way to do this, and this works fine with PyInstaller (i.e. the standalone executable works as expected, no separate Python needed). However `multiprocessing` doesn't allow full control over the process, it's not as flexible as `subprocess` (see above). And to use the latter I need some way to launch the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy over `python.exe` from your local installation and then use that as the entrypoint for `subprocess.run`. The executable should see everything the one from PyInstaller does.

As an example this file

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

python_exe = Path(sys.executable).with_stem("python")
subprocess.run([str(python_exe), "-m", "__hello__"])
```

Works as expected after the file is copied:

```
(.venv) PS dir> pyinstaller .\main.py
...
(.venv) PS dir> Copy-Item "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "dist/main"
(.venv) PS dir> .\dist\main\main.exe
Hello world!
```